# Of $\cos26^\circ$ and $\cos27^\circ$, which is greater, and why?

Tags: trigonometry

This question is supposed to be conceptual, and I am to determine which is greater without a calculator.

> So which is greater: $\cos26^\circ$ or $\cos27^\circ$?

I am not sure how to explain why it is greater and how it is determined easily.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** you can use the trigonometric identity,

$$\cos{(a)}-\cos{(a+b)}=2\sin{\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)}\sin{\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)}.$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 0):

Not rigorous however if you draw a right triangle with hypotenuse $1$ and an angle of $26$ degrees at the bottom, you have that $cos(26)=a$ where $a$ is adjacent to the angle. Now nudge the angle to $27$ degrees while keeping the hypotenuse fixed and you can see that $a$ decreases slightly. So as an angle $\theta$ increases between $0$ and $90$ degrees, $cos(\theta)$ decreases.

Apologies if redundant to link in comments; that link did not open for me.